# Apache RewriteRule - Rewrite requests matching a pattern

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I have a Wordpress installation and I want to rewrite every request that looks like this 
`".*/stories/images/requested-image.png"` to `"/stories/images/requested-image.png"`.

Basically I want to remove everything that Wordpress might put there when reading a single article, browsing through categories, dates,....

The Problem is that in this specific installation I have a bad import of articles and the paths to the images look like this `<img src='stories/images/image1.png'>`. This is no problem on the main page but on a single article page wordpress adds the permalink stuff in front of it, so I need to direct my apache to the correct path.

My current .htacces looks like this, but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
# This should make the old images (imported from joomla) work
RewriteRule    ^(.*)(/images/stories/.*)$  $2

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, the sample image path you shared is `/stories/images/requested-image.png` your rule should reflect the same path as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule    ^.*(/stories/images/.*)$  $1 [NC,L]
```